# Locate DirectX viewport

Tags: c#, directx

How do I locate the coordinates and size of a DirectX game?

My current code uses window sizes (user32.dll, GetWindowRect), which includes window chrome, but I want it to work accurately even if chrome is customized or if there is no chrome (e.g. fullscreen).

As an example, Fraps can create an overlay of the FPS of a game in a particular corner. If I wanted to do that, how do I find that window viewport?

Thanks in advance for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [GetDisplayMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174336.aspx) function.

Comment: Thanks, that may get me looking in the right direction, but it does not appear to provide coordinates, only resolution.

Comment: You don't need coordinates.  The screen is in the range -1 to 1.

Comment: Apologies. I'm new to windows development, so I don't understand your comment. Ultimately I am attempting to grab a screenshot of what is rendered. Right now, I do that by grabbing the window, but I've noticed the window chrome varying a bit and affecting screenshots. With how I'm taking screenshots in C#, I thought I needed coordinates.

Comment: You can grab the BackBuffer using GetBackBuffer.  Then read the data directly out of the D3DSurface.  Probably the best way to get a screenshot.